# 404 Error on Images Locally with WAMP/phpMyAdmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp, pantheon

I recently set up a WAMP server using phpMyAdmin and am having issues displaying images pulled from my website hosted via Pantheon. I've got everything running fine, but the images will not display.

I've exported my website's database via Pantheon and imported with phpMyadmin and the theme loads correctly, but not any images. It's running on WordPress as well. I've tried to find specific examples of this happening, but I'm not sure what the deal is. Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the Network tab on the Dev Tools to see what the actual URL is?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right you exported you wp site and imported it at a local machine ?

Have you checked / changed the site url in wp ?

If in wp the site url dont match the real url the links to the files can get broken ..

Look at our site code in browser and there you should find the image link to see what wp realy try to load.

Comment: I've exported the files (images) to what I think is the correct folder locally. It's a tar.gz file downloaded from Pantheon. The images trying to be displayed currently are also from the same directory. How can I get it to target the tar.gz file that contains all the images from my site? I am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Had to extract the contents of the .tar file into the "uploads" directory, twice. There was no explanation to do this in any of the documentation I could find, I didn't understand how .tar files work.